# Getting error on gretty when building html project for libGDX

Tags: gradle, web-applications, libgdx, gretty

I am building an html libGDX project with gradle.

After the command:

```
>gradlew html:superDev
```

I'm getting this error message:

> ```
> > Task :html:beforeRun FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> * What went wrong:
> Execution failed for task ':html:beforeRun'.
> > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':html:grettyRunnerJetty94'.
>    > Could not find org.gretty:gretty-runner-jetty94:3.0.2.
>      Searched in the following locations:
>
>        - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/gretty/gretty-runner-jetty94/3.0.2/gretty-runner-jetty94-3.0.2.pom
>        - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/gretty/gretty-runner-jetty94/3.0.2/gretty-runner-jetty94-3.0.2.pom
>        - https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/gretty/gretty-runner-jetty94/3.0.2/gretty-runner-jetty94-3.0.2.pom
>        - https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/gretty/gretty-runner-jetty94/3.0.2/gretty-runner-jetty94-3.0.2.pom
>      Required by:
>          project :html
> ```

Answer (score 2):

To solve this problem, edit the file build.gradle inside your project directory, to reflect the new version of gretty (present is 3.0.3, find any update at https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.gretty).

Look for section "buildscript" subsection "dependencies":

```
dependencies {
    classpath "gradle.plugin.org.gretty:gretty:3.0.3"      
}
```

Replace:

```
    classpath 'org.gretty:gretty:3.0.2'
```

(or whatever wrong version text)

With:

```
    classpath "gradle.plugin.org.gretty:gretty:3.0.3"
```

(or whatever line of text version present in the gradle link https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.gretty)

At the "allprojects" section, look for the "repositories" subsection and add the maven repository as presented in the link https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.gretty.

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    google()
    maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
}
```

Save the file and rebuild your project with:

```
    >gradlew html:superDev
```